# Jax-rs Response to Angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, json

I am trying to send a JSON response(jax-rs). The JSON contains a date value in it. However, I am getting trouble to pass the date as value attribute in html form through angular ng-model. 
Here is the java method

```
@POST
@Path("/selectedjob")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getSelectedJob(JSONArray selected){
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Job j = em.find(Job.class, Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(selected.get(0))));
    return Response.status(200).entity(j).build();
}
```

The Json on my client side is

```
{"date":"2012-02-02","invoiced":false,"destination":"lskdjf","invoiceNumber":null,"vehicleRegno":"djksladfi","product":"lskdjf","loadedFrom":"slkjf","rate":45,"amount":345646,"deliveryNo":null,"qtyLoaded":12,"id":22}
```

Now I want this data to appear as default value in the following HTML form, (All others are working except for the date)

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="editJob()">
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <label for="Date"> Date</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="job.date">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <label for="vehicle">Vehicle</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="job.vehicleRegno">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <label for="Loaded">Loaded From</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="job.loadedFrom">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <label for="Destination">Destination</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="job.destination">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <label for="Product">Product</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="job.product">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <label for="Quantity">Quantity Loaded</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="job.qtyLoaded">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <label for="Rate">Rate</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="job.rate">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <label for="Amount">Amount</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="job.amount">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <label for="Delivery">Delivery Note Number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="job.deliveryNo">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-body -->

  <div class="box-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" ng-click="showdetails(true)">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I have also come with this issue, First, you should format this date using

`DateAdapter.java`

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date date) {
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String dateStr) {
        try {
            return dateFormat.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException();
        }
    }
}
```

And then, you can import `DateAdapter` class to your `Job` class Date property like this:

```
Job.java

{

...
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    private Date date;

...

}
```

Hope it works!